# How to combine the data of each row with the title name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:
[image]

and I wish to add every row of data with the column name:
[image]

Which the **-test** will be change once the column which name test are change, anyone can share me your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a string to a string series

```
df.indicator += '-test`
```

If you want it to be dynamic, you'll have to specify which column it is

```
df.indicator += '-' + df.columns[2]
```

If you want this to be repeated

```
df.indicator = df.indicator.str.split('-').str[0] + '-' + df.columns[2]
```

Comment: it work , but once I add the statement my **ww** column and **test** column disappear already...

Comment: @ShiJieTio you'll have to explain your work flow in more detail.

Comment: Actually, I need to split in two table from the picture above , one table is indicator column + ww another one column is indicator + test, so after add the indicator data with the name of column I will join up this two table then after that i can remove the header